# EF Property pointing to a member within a member

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4.1, xml-deserialization

**Context:**
I am trying to use the same set of models for both XML deserialization and EF 4.1 persistance of data.  *I cannot change either the existing XSD or the database schema.*

**Problem:**
The XML structure doesn't line up with the table structure very well for a few models.  Currently a database one-to-many relationship is defined in the (XML-based) models as a three level hierarchy of parent-child-child.  This causes the error:

> The expression 't => t.PhysicalDetails.PhysicalFeatures' 
>   is not a valid property expression.

**Participant**

```
class Participant {
  public PhysicalDetailsType PhysicalDetails { get; set; }
}
```

**PhysicalDetailsType**

```
class PhysicalDetailsType {
  [XmlArray("PersonPhysicalFeature")]
  public List<PhysicalFeatureType> PhysicalFeatures { get; set; }
}
```

**PhysicalFeatureType**

```
class PhysicalFeatureType {
  public int CaseSk { get; set; }
  public int ParticipantSk { get; set; }
  public Participant participant { get; set; }
}
```

**PhysicalFeatureType EF Mapping**

```
class PhysicalFeatureMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PhysicalFeatureType> {
  HasRequired(t => t.Participant)
    .WithMany(t => t.PhysicalDetails.PhysicalFeatures)
    .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.CaseSk, d.ParticipantSk});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I've come up with so far is creating a proxy property that just hides the nesting:

**Participant**

```
class Participant {
  public PhysicalDetailsType PhysicalDetails { get; set; }
  public List<PhysicalFeatureType> PhysicalFeatures {
    get { return PhysicalDetails.PhysicalFeatures; }
    set { Physicaldetails.PhysicalFeatures = value; }
  }
}
```

Seems to be working so far.

Comment: Great idea! I assume that you either need to instantiate the `PhysicalDetails` and `PhysicalDetails.PhysicalFeatures` in the constructor or you need a setter. Because if you read for instance a `Participant` from the DB including the `PhysicalFeatures` collection EF will complain about the missing setter if `PhysicalDetails.PhysicalFeatures` is `null`. (It cannot materialize the data into the `PhysicalFeatures` property).

Comment: I did have to add a setter as EF didn't consider it a Property without one.  Fortunately I won't really need it as I'm only going one direction (into the database).

Answer (score 0):

The expression in all the mapping methods (`HasRequired`, `WithMany`, etc.) must specify a property which is *declared* on the generic type of the method (the lambda variable `t` which is of type `Participant` in your example). `Participant` doesn't have a property `PhysicalDetails.PhysicalFeatures`. So to say, the expression cannot contain more than one dot.

If I understand right, you only have *two tables* in the DB (for `Participant` and `PhysicalFeatureType`) but *three classes* in your model (with the additional `PhysicalDetailsType` in between). The `PhysicalDetailsType` is an "intermediate" type, necessary for the one-to-many relationship in the model but not existing as table in the database, right? (Just to understand, not that I would have an idea how to map this or if it's possible at all.)

Comment: You're correct about the table-model relationship.  Deserialization results in three models with only the outer two being mapped to tables.

Comment: @Jeff: OK, let's wait if someone has an idea to define a working mapping. If have no clue if and how this is possible.

Comment: An alternative (that I'd like to avoid if possible) is to change the deserialization config so that it flattens out the XML structure when going into the models.  No clue if this is possible either.